# using cors still it show cors error in node app

Tags: javascript, express, cors

I'm using cors in my server like this

## app.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const express = require('express');
const messageRoutes = require('./routes/messageRoutes');
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())
app.use('/api/msg',messageRoutes);
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res
      .status(200)
      .send('Hello server is running')
      .end();
  });
module.exports=app;
```

## server.js

```
const app = require("./app");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const connectDatabase = require('./database.js');
// dotenv.config({path:'./config.env'});
connectDatabase();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4101;
app.listen(PORT);
```

this is a post request from plain vanilla javascript

```
 let _data = {
        message,
        sender
    }
    await fetch('https://profoliobackend.herokuapp.com/api/msg/sendmessage', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(_data),
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log("thanks for feedback");
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    })
```

still I'm getting cors issue.  I'm using express and node js as backEnd and vanilla javascript as frontend.

Comment: `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header and has no place in a request - you can't beat CORS from the browser - you tagged `express` so you need to fix your server side

Comment: yes true. but I have used cors in server. and it still didnt worked

Comment: @NarendraDewasi You need to explicitly allow the `Content-Type` request header in your CORS configuration. Why? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests. How? See https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html#configuration-options.

Comment: Please show the server code, since that's what you've done wrong ... also, remove the response header from the request, since that can cause otherwise well configured CORS to fail

Comment: @Bravo , I have added my server-side code. can you check

Comment: as I suspected, you aren't using CORS middleware as recommended by jub0bs **yesterday**

Comment: I did not get. can you please correct my code